# CentOS 7: power button cannot shutdown before user login (not after)

Tags: centos7

After user login, the power button action can be changed by Applications > Utilities > Tweak Tool > Shell > Power button action. It does not work before login. I have already tried

https://askubuntu.com/questions/362914/how-to-prevent-the-power-button-to-shutdown-directly-the-system

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159316/graceful-shutdown-via-power-button

How to make it work? I am building a server without keyboard and monitor so the power button is important for me.

Comment: Why are you installing a GUI on the server, then?

Comment: Because I am new to Linux. GUI is more intuitive and easy to understand for me. I understand that many settings cannot make it via GUI, so command is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution in here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394405/how-can-i-regain-the-power-button-shutdown-functionality-on-centos-7-with-gnome?noredirect=1&lq=1

```
yum -y install acpid
systemctl enable acpid
systemctl start acpid
```

The suspend and hibernate in the power setting will no longer be working.

Answer (score 0):

1.- sudo vim /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn

2.- Add # to comment line: #action=/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh

3.- Add a new line: action=/sbin/poweroff

4.- Save file

5.- Open a console and type: sudo acpid restart